# Combination with lengths

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are 15 appointments that need to ship out. They can ship out of 3 different loading areas. Each loading area can ship out 5  appointments.

How many different ways can the 15 appointments ship out

What would the math formula look like to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use combinations (the order doesn't matter): $\binom{15}{5}\times\binom{10}{5}\times\binom{5}{5}$.

Comment: If i am calculating correctly this number is quite large

Comment: Can you please confirm total, i'm not certain I'm doing this correctly